# Angular - boolean value doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm facing issue with my app.
I'm trying to create a list of checkboxes, when the checkbox is clicked the value should be true and when clicked again the value should be false. Simple.

Here is my html

```
  <li *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxSelect">
      <div class="checkbox-style">
          <input type="checkbox" name ="{{checkbox.inputName}}" 
                [checked]="checkbox.name"
                (change)="checkbox.name= !checkbox.name"/>
             <div class="state">
                 <label>{{checkbox.label}}</label>
             </div>
      </div>
  </li>
```

Here is my component.ts

```
showFirstName = true;
showLastName = true;

checkboxSelect: any[] = [{
        label: 'First name',
        name: this.showFirstName,
        inputName: 'showFirstName'
    }, {
        label: 'Last name',
        name: this.showLastName,
        inputName: 'showLastName'

    },
];
```

Everything is working except my 'name' value doesn't change to true/false when clicked.

On the other hand when I put that straight to html without *ngFor it's working

```
  <li>
      <div class="checkbox-style">
          <input type="checkbox" name = "firstName"
                [checked]="showFirstName"
                (change)="showFirstName = !showFirstName"/>
             <div class="state">
                 <label>First Name</label>
             </div>
      </div>
  </li>
```

I wasn't so clear, my goal is to display divs depend on true/false

```
 <div *ngIf="showFirstName" scope="col">First name</div>
<div *ngIf="showLastName" scope="col">Second name</div>
```

But it doesn't change at all.

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: can you create a minimal stackblitz demo ?

Comment: you should probably be using ngModel for this, but your expectations / issue is unclear.

Comment: Can't understand from the question.

Comment: Your code works without any issue: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfltoa. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Look here, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ww1hyl 
I'm trying to display/hide these divs depnend on true/false but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are trying to use variables `showFirstName` and `showLastName` that aren't modified by the event handler to show/hide strings `First Name` and `Last Name`. To make the value binding persist between two variables, you could make them objects. Objects are *usually* passed by reference in Javascript. Try the following

Controller

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showFirstName = { status: true };
  showLastName = { status: true };

  checkboxSelect: any[] = [{
    label: 'First name',
    name: this.showFirstName,
    inputName: 'showFirstName'
  }, {
    label: 'Last name',
    name: this.showLastName,
    inputName: 'showLastName'

  }, ];

  checkStatus() {
    console.log(this.checkboxSelect[0].name, this.checkboxSelect[1].name);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<li *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxSelect">
  <div class="checkbox-style">
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{checkbox.inputName}}" [checked]="checkbox.name.status"
      (change)="checkbox.name.status = !checkbox.name.status; checkStatus()" />
    <div class="state">
      <label>{{checkbox.label}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>

<table>
  <th *ngIf="showFirstName.status" scope="col">First Name</th>
  <th *ngIf="showLastName.status" scope="col">Last Name</th>
</table>
```

Note: Using object reference to control the state of variables could get very tangled later in development. Better way would be to think of a different structure.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cfltoa)

Comment: And it looks like I can use also use [(ngModel)]="checkbox.name.status" instead of   (change)="checkbox.name.status = !checkbox.name.status")

Comment: You can. It's another way of binding controller variables in Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to :-

```
<li *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxSelect">
      <div class="checkbox-style">
          <input type="checkbox" [name] ="checkbox.inputName" 
                [checked]="checkbox.name"
                (change)="checkbox.name = !checkbox.name"/>
             <div class="state">
                 <label>{{checkbox.label}}</label>
             </div>
      </div>
  </li>
```

Comment: It's working, the value changes to true/false but there is another problem. My another piece of html doesn't change 
  <th *ngIf="showFirstName" scope="col">First Name</th>
                        <th *ngIf="showLastName" scope="col">Last Name</th>

Comment: what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Angular ngModel? Then you don't need to define change handler.

```
<li *ngFor="let checkbox of checkboxSelect">
      <div class="checkbox-style">
          <input type="checkbox" name ="{{checkbox.inputName}}" 
                [(ngModel)] ="checkbox.name"/>
             <div class="state">
                 <label>{{checkbox.label}}</label>
             </div>
      </div>
  </li>
```